# How to convert Convert byte[] of C# to std::vector<unsigned char> of C++ (vice versa)?

Tags: c#, c++, converters

I want to call `std::vector<unsigned char> writeApplet(std::vector<unsigned char> req)` of C++ function from C#.

I'm confusing because `writeApplet` have input parameters and output as `std::vector<unsigned char>`, while the values will be pass to `writeApplet` is `byte[]` in C#.

How to convert Convert `byte[]` of C# to `std::vector<unsigned char>` of C++ (vice versa)?
Thanks.

dllmain.cpp (C++)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "RemoteTypeJCIDEProxy.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define DllExport __declspec(dllexport)

#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

    static auto client = new RemoteTypeJCIDEProxy();


    DllExport std::vector<unsigned char> writeApplet(std::vector<unsigned char> req) {
        if (client != NULL) {
            std::vector<unsigned char> apdu(req);

            std::vector<unsigned char> rsp;
            client->AckTransimit(apdu, rsp);

            return rsp;
        }
    }

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

hostJCIDE.cs (C#)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace hostJCIDE
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string remoteJCIDEdll = @"remoteJCIDE.dll";

        [DllImport(remoteJCIDEdll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern byte[] writeApplet(byte[] req);


        private static string BytesToString(byte[] ba)
        {
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in ba)
            {
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
            }
            return hex.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // request to C++
            byte[] req = new byte[] { 0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00 };
            Console.WriteLine("Request: " + BytesToString(req));

            // response from C++
            byte[] res = writeApplet(req);
            Console.WriteLine("Response: " + BytesToString(res));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt this is possible that c# can marshal a std::vector correctly. Even when it was a c++ user of that method the cases where that works are rather scant. You would need to use identical compilers with almost identical settings on both ends. And here we are talking about a completely different platform with c#. I would suggest using a simple array in the exported  signature and mapping the array to a vector in your c++ code.

Comment: You will very likely need to write a P/Invoke mechanism that allows transfer between a c# byte[] and a C (not C++) byte* (with length), with a follow-on mechanism that wraps that up as a vector.  The same kind of thing will be needed in the reverse direction.  P/Invoke works with straight C and with COM (via COM-Interop), it doesn't play well with C++.